# Form a RegEx for asp.net asp:RegularExpressionValidator

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex

I have a following requirement for validating the string in text box control:

1. The No should be of 12 Characters Maximum and minimum of 11
   Characters.
2. First 11 Characters should be Numbers
3. The 12th Characters should be an Alphabet.

I practiced to form the regular expression using [this RegEx builder](http://regex.cryer.info/). My string is `^([0-9]{11}[a-zA-Z]{1}){11,12}$`. But my validation is not working. As a beginner in the asp.net I don't have much idea about forming the RegEx. What am I missing?

I have used `asp:RegularExpressionValidator` control.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to make the last `[A-Za-z]` as optional.

```
@"^\d{11}[A-Za-z]?$"
```